# Why can't the ASM powershell module access some subscriptions?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Are the Azure subscriptions tied to ARM model or ASM model?

I got different results when I run `Get-AzureRmSubscription` (ARM based) and `Get-AzureSubscription` (ASM based). I thought I should get similar result.

I have AzureRM (6.4.0) and Azure (5.3.1). I already run `Add-AzureAccount` (ASM), `Add-AzureRmAccount` (ARM), `Connect-AzureRmAccount` (ARM).

I am not able to find any documentation. I found this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5a9d94e-882d-4443-bd18-fa55d95aed41/getazuresubscription-vs-getazurermsubscription?forum=azurescripting but it said a subscription is not inherently ASM or ARM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, if the subscription was created after a certain time, it is quite possible that the `Get-AzureSubscription` i.e. service manager api is not available to that subscription.

This would ensure that **all Resources** are created with the new resource manager api only. The ARM powershell is just for ARM models, and the ASM powershell is just for ASM models.

For more details about ARM and ASM , you could refer to the articles, [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model) and [2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2016/12/22/difference-between-azure-service-manager-and-azure-resource-manager/).

Comment: Thanks Joy. I think you are right. ASM api is not available for some subscriptions. I am looking for some references. I can't find that information in both of your links. Could you please quote some words if I miss out in those articles so I can search ?

Comment: @Cloudy I got the information in the link, you could find it in the MSFT-engineer's reply. screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIJzz.png

Comment: Both of your articles that you linked don't have any comment. Can you please give me the link to that MSFT-engineer's reply? Thanks. I just want to keep it as a proof if other people asked the same question. If you look at my link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5a9d94e-882d-4443-bd18-fa55d95aed41/getazuresubscription-vs-getazurermsubscription?forum=azurescripting, Sadiqh Ahmed (MSFT) said that the subscription are not tied to ASM or ARM.

Comment: @Cloudy Oh...so sorry for my oversight, I forget to post it, this is the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6bdb2f3-c3b0-4a99-b75d-3493cf63e03b/loginazurermaccount-vs-addazureaccount), you could refer to it.

Comment: In order to resolved this error “No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure Service Management (RDFE). This means that the logged in user is not an administrator or co-administrator for any account."”.

I would suggest you, go to your Subscriptions => Select your subscription => Access control (IAM) => Select the user => Add as co-administrator

Refer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77d36a5e-9c98-4003-bc52-367c00156b40/how-to-change-subscription?forum=azurescripting

Comment: @PRADEEPCHEEKATLA I know how to fix the error, I quote this link just to explain the OP's issue.

Comment: @ PRADEEP  I didn't say I was getting any error, man. It just doesn't show .. And I won't be able to make myself co-admin in those subscriptions as well. but thanks.

Comment: @JoyWang Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Azure RM PowerShell models are tied to ARM models.

The Azure classic deployment model is not supported by this version of Azure PowerShell. For support for classic deployments, follow the instructions in [Install the Azure PowerShell Service Management module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/install-azure-ps?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).

**You may use the following steps to select the right subscription.**

**For ASM model:**

Sign in to your account for the classic model.

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

Get the available subscriptions by using the following command:

```
Get-AzureSubscription | Sort SubscriptionName | Select SubscriptionName
```

Set your Azure subscription for the current session. This example sets the default subscription to My Azure Subscription. Replace the example subscription name with your own.

```
Select-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName "My Azure Subscription"
```

**For ARM model:**

Sign in to your account for the ARM model.

```
 Add-AzureRmAccount
```

To change the current subscription, use the following steps:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

It will List all your subscriptions.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

The SubscriptionID can be found in the output of the Get-AzureRmSubscription. You can also use the SubscriptionName.

```
(Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription
```

Confirm that you have selected the right subscription.

Comment: Azure (5.3.1) is for ASM. I did the same but some subscriptions are still missing if I use ASM.

Comment: When you use Add-AzureAccount are you seeing any error message on subscription which are missing?

Comment: no error message. It just doesn't show those subscription.

Comment: In order to resolved this error “No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure Service Management (RDFE). This means that the logged in user is not an administrator or co-administrator for any account."”.

I would suggest you, go to your Subscriptions => Select your subscription => Access control (IAM) => Select the user => Add as co-administrator

Refer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77d36a5e-9c98-4003-bc52-367c00156b40/how-to-change-subscription?forum=azurescripting

Comment: I didn't say I was getting any error, man. It just doesn't show .. And I won't be able to make myself co-admin in those subscriptions as well. but thanks.